# How to correctly list menu items for a specific ul/li level using xpath and python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

To describe the problem in general. I try to finish function to extract information from menu. The menu has more levels of submenu (ul). I have recursive function in python `def extract_data(parent_depth, section, url_dirname, ul_obj, in_submenu=False)`  I call it in main loop which goes through the first level. This is called extract_data(parent_depth, section, url_dirname, ul_obj, in_submenu). parent_depth is 1. The pseudo-html-code and html-code here is from the level 2 because in the function I need to access the items of level 2.

To simplify the problem. I will use pseudo html code, changing the a tag for link.

```
li class="wnd-with-submenu"
   LINK LEVEL 1
   ul class="level-2"
      li
         **link level 2 A**
      /li
      li
         **link level 2 B**
      li
      li class="wnd-with-submenu"
         **link LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU**
         ul class="level-3"
         li
*         link level 3 D DON'T INCLUDE !!*
         /li
         /ul
      /li
   /ul
/li
```

So I need to get the level 2 items. The link level 2 C with submenu is also just "a" tag (link contains span and title of article). There is NOT submenu in the link. The submenu is after the link. That is the ul class="level-3". Now this is the main problem. How can I obtain the li items (or possibly "a" links) without any element from the ul level 3?

I tried various attempts:

```
li_obj = ul_obj[0].xpath('.//li[@class="wnd-with-submenu"]')
```

This listed the first link in the item "with submenu" and the nested "li"s (article titles) too. That is wrong.

```
li_obj = ul_obj[0].xpath('.//li[@class="wnd-with-submenu" or not(@class)]')
```

This was similar problem, it listed those "li"s without class attribute, and the first link (level 2 article title). But is also included the nested items and links. That is wrong.

```
li_obj = ul_obj[0].xpath('.//li[not(.//ul[@class="level-3"]//ancestor::li[@class="wnd-with-submenu"])]//a')
```

This was supposed to output all the li elements in the ul list (2nd level) without the nested menu. However, it doesn't work as expected. Instead, it displays items without a nested menu, omits the first nested item, and displays the rest of the nested items. This is a mistake. **The nested items should not be included at all** (that's what I want to handle in a separate function).

I believe that the expression **not(.//ul) is interpreted in a way that completely excludes the items containing li elements at the 2nd level, instead of providing only the link from these li elements at the 2nd level**.

Simplified html code:

```
<li class="wnd-with-submenu">
    <a class="menu-item">LINK LEVEL 1</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li>
            <a>link level 2 A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>link level 2 B</a>           
        </li>
        <li class="wnd-with-submenu">
            <a>LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU</a>
            <ul class="level-3">
            <li>
            <a>link level 3 D DON'T!!</a>   
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So here is the question, to make it as easy as possible. I need to include in the list the li items on the same level (for this case of function call the level is 2). This include links with names and hrefs. The main problem is that there are either included the the nested links like level 3 D or in the case of the last code, there is LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU skipped which is wrong, and link level 3 D is included, which is also wrong. So if it is possible help me to find either a valid rule to find only the links from level 2, or a way how to temporally remove the nested ul list to get the correct level 2 article names and hrefs. So to give you an idea of what is the purpose of the code - I could call the function again and continue to extract the names and href for level 3. But I ask just for the code to extract the list for level 2.

Comment: There are two missing close tags, please correct your html.

Comment: @Hemann12: I tried to correct. I hope now it's more clear

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get links as requestd

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse('tmp.html')
c = doc.xpath('//li[parent::ul[@class="level-2"] and not(parent::ul[@class="level-3"])]/a')
for ele in c:
    print(ele.text)
```

Result

```
link level 2 A
link level 2 B
LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Simple HTML and XHTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    le = 0
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        global le
        self.le += 1
        if tag == 'li':
            pass
            #print("start tag:", self.le, tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        global le
        self.le -= 1
        if tag == 'li':
            pass
            #print("end tag :", self.le, tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        lev_list =[8] # Write  here the levels to print
        if '\n' not in data and self.le in lev_list:
            print("data  :", repr(data))

parser = MyHTMLParser()

with open("list.html", 'r') as htm:
    html = htm.read()

parser.feed(html)
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <li class="wnd-with-submenu">
    <a class="menu-item">LINK LEVEL 1</a>
    <ul class="level-2">
        <li>
            <a>link level 2 A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>link level 2 B</a>           
        </li>
        <li class="wnd-with-submenu">
            <a>LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU</a>
            <ul class="level-3">
            <li>
            <a>link level 3 D DON'T!!</a>   
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
data  : 'link level 2 A'
data  : 'link level 2 B'
data  : 'LEVEL 2 C with SUBMENU'
```